# What exactly is Datum in PostgreSQL C Language functions?

Tags: c, postgresql

So far I know that `Datum` is one of the data types used in C language functions in PostgreSQL which can represent any value in valid SQL type. What I am not getting is that, if it can hold any type of value, then how does the calling function know the data type of the value returned by called function ? Is Datum internally a structure which contains such additional information? Please explain.

Answer (score 5):

From PostgreSQL mailing list, quoting [rsmogura](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/e4f370d4495d809dda357c95621c444c%40mail.softperience.eu):

> [...] in simple 
>    words, datum is like `void *` with additional size header.

and [Tom Lane](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/22559.1277304590%40sss.pgh.pa.us):

> It's the backend-internal representation of a single value of any SQL
>   data type.  The code using the `Datum` has to know which type it is,
>   since the `Datum` itself doesn't contain that information.  Usually,
>   C code will work with a value in a "native" representation, and then
>   convert to or from `Datum` in order to pass the value through
>   data-type-independent interfaces.

The `Datum` is defined as [`typedef uintptr_t Datum`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/aa2ba50c2c13dd35a95a91638aa0a2b88c6df1eb/src/include/postgres.h#L367), therefore it is 4 or 8 bytes on the platforms supported by PostgreSQL

Answer (score 5):

`Datum` is the generic type to hold the internal representation of an — er — datum that can be stored in a PostgreSQL table. It is defined in `postgres.h`, and the comment is instructive:

```
/*
 * A Datum contains either a value of a pass-by-value type or a pointer to a
 * value of a pass-by-reference type.  Therefore, we require:
 *
 * sizeof(Datum) == sizeof(void *) == 4 or 8
 *
 * The macros below and the analogous macros for other types should be used to
 * convert between a Datum and the appropriate C type.
 */
```

You use the `DatumGet*` macros to cast it to one of the specific data types.

`Datum` does not contain any information about the data type, this knowledge has to come from elsewhere.

When writing a C function, the data type of the arguments will always be as declared in the function.